# Adding Class on Scroll Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working in Vue.js and would like to conditionally display a back to top button when the user scrolls past a certain point. What am I doing wrong (no JQuery)?

In my template:

```
<div class="scroll">
  <span class="scroll_button">Top</span>
</div>
```

In my mounted() function

```
const toTop = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll').addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.scrollY > 0) {
    this.classList.add('shown')
  }
});
toTop();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 data () {
   return {
   scrolled: false
   };
  },
    methods: {
       handleScroll () {
       this.scrolled = window.scrollY > 0;
     }
    },
    created () {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    }
```

Comment: Yes!  No need to touch the DOM directly, let Vue do the work.  The only part of this answer that's missing is `:class="{'shown': scrolled}"` on the element that needs the classname added